# Export iPad2 Slideshow with Origami Transitions

Tags: ipad

I'm trying to export a slideshow from my iPad2. I can email or share single photos, of course, but how do you share or export a slideshow?
I especially want to retain the origami transition effect to share on YouTube or export to iMove. Is there a way? Or a program that creates the origami effect?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do this with the iOS iPhoto app, so I suggest you check out iPhoto for OS X. You have the ability to create slideshows, set origami as the theme and then export them to video. I do it all the time & it works like a charm.

I'm using iPhoto '11 v. 9.2.3.

[image]